# COM exception occurs but not always

Tags: c#, .net

I have code where i am opening excel document, checking the document data (for grading) and then preparing another excel as resultExcel with 1 more sheet showing grades for that excel.

It is working fine. But sometimes it throws COM exception and the addition sheet m adding is added as blank.
Again next time when i check, it works completely fine with same file also.

I am confused whether its due to any system problem.I think it is due to some COM exception but i don't know does COM exception occurs due to system;s problem ??

Comment: can you check and post the InnerException, also it would be better if you post the line(s) of code which cause(s) exceptions

Comment: I guess, you are working with excel functions, through interop (reflection based mechanism), which sometimes throw such errors. Have you tryed using helping libraries like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)? Or maybe your problem caused of incorrect worksheet number, that you're trying to access?

Comment: Are you getting anything in the Event Viewer?